# Yii CGridView. Show columns from not related tables

Tags: php, yii, yii-widgets

Currently I have CGridView with columns from few joined tables, but also I need to add additional columns from other table, and I can not join it with first tables, because there is no relations between them.

Second table `assessment_rate`:

```
id  title_id    rate    users_id    date_entry
0   2137        0       1           2013-08-28 08:43:54.000000
1   2139        1       1           2013-08-28 08:47:13.000000
2   2140        2       1           2013-08-28 08:57:44.000000
3   2141        3       1           2013-08-28 08:59:10.000000
```

I need to get 4 additional columns in CGridView with radio buttons generated (one buttom per column) from the table above (with values 0,1,2,3).

model file:

```
class form extends CActiveRecord {

public function init() {
    Yii::import('application.modules.admin.models.user');
    Yii::import('application.modules.admin.models.language');
}

public function tableName() {
    return 'ass_competence';
}

public function relations() {

    return array(
        'lan' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'language', 'title_id'),
        'lan_desc' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'language', 'description_title_id'),
        'use' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'user', 'users_id'),
        'rela' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'relation', array('id' => 'record_id')),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'lan.name_lt' => Yii::app()->reg->lang['title'],
        'use.username' => Yii::app()->reg->lang['user'],
        'lan_desc.name_lt' => Yii::app()->reg->lang['description'],
        'date_entry' => Yii::app()->reg->lang['date_entry'],
        'assessment' => Yii::app()->reg->lang['assessment'],
    );
}

public function search() {

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->with = array('use', 'lan', 'rela', 'lan_desc');
    $criteria->addCondition('rela.record_id IS NULL');
    $criteria->group = 't.id';
    $criteria->order = 't.id ASC';

    $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria;


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}

public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
    return parent::model($className);
}

}
```

controller file:

```
class FormController extends ControllerDefault {

public $model_name = 'Form';

public function beforeActionConfig() {


    $this->reg['title'] = Yii::app()->reg->lang['players'];
}

public function actionIndex() {
    $model = new form('search');
    $columns_top = array('' => 2,
        Yii::app()->reg->lang['assessment'] => 4,
    );
    $columns_main = array('lan.name_lt',
        'lan_desc.name_lt',
        'CountryName' => array(
            'header' => 'Country',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'value' => '1',
        ),
    );

    $dataProvider = $model->search();
    $this->render('index', array('model' => $model, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'columns_main' => $columns_main, 'columns_top' => $columns_top));
}

}
```

view file:

```
$this->widget('CGridViewPlus', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'addingHeaders' => array(
        $columns_top, // first header row
    ),
    'columns' => $columns_main //second header row
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use a  [radioButtonList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#radioButtonList-detail) and specify that the column is of a `raw` type:

```
'columns'=>array(
    ... //other columns
    array(
        'name'=> 'test',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value' => 'CHtml::radioButtonList("test", $select,array("key" => "value"), array("template" => "{input}", "separator"=>" "))',
            ),
    ),
),
```

If you don't know how to use a radioButtonList you should check the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#radioButtonList-detail) about it

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. I know about `radioButtonList`, but it generates all radio buttons in one column :/

Comment: So use 3 columns and in each column put a CHtml::radioButton() object!